# Problemas con las Carpetas estáticas en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs

Hola a todos estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Node.js y sus rutas con express, pero tengo un problema.

Las rutas principales como por ejemplo **http://localhost:3000/mascotas** funcionan perfecto  me refiero a que si reconocen las rutas estáticas como por ejemplo las imagenes,los estilos css y los de bootstrap estoy llamando a la ruta así **app.use("/mascotas",require("./Routers/Mascotas"));** en mi **App.js**

ESTE ES MI ROUTER DE MASCOTA

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const modelo = require("../Model/data");





router.get("/",async function(req,res){

   try{
   const arrayMascotas = await modelo.find();
   res.render("mascotas",{mascotas: arrayMascotas});
   }catch(e){

       console.log("No se pudo obtener los datos",e);
   };
});

router.get("/crear",function(req,res){

   res.render("crear");

});


router.get("/:id",async function(req,res){


   const id = req.params.id;

   try{

       //BUSCA UNA MASCOTA CON EL ID QUE HEMOS TOMADO DE LA SOLICITUD
       const id_mascota = await modelo.findOne({_id:id});

       res.render("detalle",{
           id_mascota:id_mascota,
           error: false
       });


   }catch(e){

       res.render("detalle",{
           mensaje: "Error al obtener la informacion de la mascota",
           error: true
       });

   }


  

});
```

Mi problema va es que por que mis archivos que llamo en render no funcionan sus estilos solo el primero

```
router.get("/",async function(req,res){

   try{
   const arrayMascotas = await modelo.find();
   res.render("mascotas",{mascotas: arrayMascotas});
   }catch(e){

       console.log("No se pudo obtener los datos",e);
   };
})
```

De esta forma estoy llamando a mis carpetas estaticas

```
app.use(express.static('Css'));
app.use(express.static('Img'));
app.use(express.static('Fonts'));
app.use(express.static("Bootstrap"));
```

Comment: como esta configurado tu motor de plantillas?

Comment: De esta manera amigo `app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views",__dirname+"/Views");`